# Use custom interceptors for the response

Tags: nest, interceptor

I'm using a global interceptor to get response like:

```
{
  "data": "",
  "statusCode": int
  "message": "string"
}
```

so I created the interceptor file

```
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, NestInterceptor } from "@nestjs/common";
import { map, Observable } from "rxjs";

export interface Response<T> {
    data: T;
}

@Injectable()
export class TransformationInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<Response<T>> {
        return next.handle().pipe(map(data => ({ 
            data: data,
            statusCode: context.switchToHttp().getResponse().statusCode,
            message: data.message
        })));
    }
}
```

and put it into my `main.ts`

In my controller I have:

```
  @Patch('/:userId')
  @HttpCode(201)
  public async updateUser(    
    @Param('userId') userId: string,
    @Body() userUpdate: UpdateUserDto): Promise<any> {      
    return await this.usersService.update(userId, userUpdate);    
  }
```

and the result is:

```
{
  "data": {
    "_id": "621d07d9ea0cdc600fae0f02",    
    "username": "foo",
    "name": "stringwwww",
    "__v": 0
  },
  "statusCode": 201
}
```

If I want to add my custom message, I need to return an object like:

```
@Patch('/:userId')
  @HttpCode(201)
  public async updateUser(    
    @Param('userId') userId: string,
    @Body() userUpdate: UpdateUserDto): Promise<any> {      
    const result = await this.usersService.update(userId, userUpdate);    
    return { message: 'User updated', result };    
  }
```

but in that case I have twice message and the structure is not correct:

```
{
  "data": {
    "message": "User updated",
    "result": {
      "_id": "621d07d9ea0cdc600fae0f02",
      "username": "foo",
      "name": "stringwwww",
      "__v": 0
    }
  },
  "statusCode": 201,
  "message": "User updated"
}
```

How can I set a custom (optional) message?

```
I can modify my interceptors like:
@Injectable()
export class TransformationInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<Response<T>> {
        return next.handle().pipe(map(data => ({ 
            data: data.res,
            statusCode: context.switchToHttp().getResponse().statusCode,
            message: data.message
        })));
    }
}
```

and my controller like:

```
@Patch('/:userId')
  @HttpCode(201)
  public async updateUser(    
    @Param('userId') userId: string,
    @Body() userUpdate: UpdateUserDto): Promise<any> {      
    const result = await this.usersService.update(userId, userUpdate);    
    return { message: 'User updated', res: result };    
  }
```

and I will get the correct form, but I don't want to add

```
return { message: 'User updated', res: result };
```

for each controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is as below, but you will be bound to a fixed message per controller

Create a response decorator (response.decorator.ts)

```js
    import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common'
    
    export const ResponseMessageKey = 'ResponseMessageKey'
    export const ResponseMessage = (message: string) => SetMetadata(ResponseMessageKey, message)
```

Create a constants file for your responses (response.constants.ts)

```js
    export const USER_INSERTED = 'User Inserted'
    export const USER_UPDATED = 'User Updated'
    export const USER_DELETED = 'User Deleted'
```

Add the decorator to your controller to set response message metadata

```js
    @Patch('/:userId')
    @HttpCode(201)
    @ResponseMessage(USER_UPDATED)
    public async updateUser(    
      @Param('userId') userId: string,
      @Body() userUpdate: UpdateUserDto
    ): Promise<any> {      
      const result = await this.usersService.update(userId, userUpdate);    
      return result;    
    }
```

Update your interceptor to read the response message from the metadata set on the controller and add it in the response

```js
    import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core'

    @Injectable()
    export class TransformationInterceptor<T>
      implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>>
    {
      constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {}

      intercept(
        context: ExecutionContext,
        next: CallHandler
      ): Observable<Response<T>> {
        const responseMessage = this.reflector.get<string>(
          ResponseMessageKey,
          context.getHandler()
        ) ?? ''

        return next.handle().pipe(
          map((data) => ({
            data,
            statusCode: context.switchToHttp().getResponse().statusCode,
            message: responseMessage
          }))
        )
      }
    }
```

You could extend this approach to set a list of strings/objects as possible responses (metadata), and based on response code in interceptor, send a particular message as `response.message`

Comment: this decorator thing seems to be limiting, it will always return the message that we have as success, what if the user we are trying to update is not found, how we'll send the error message?